# HLS.js get video size from codec

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming

The video size reported by the current level always returns 0. I guess this just reads whatever info is in MetaData good or bad.

```
  var level = hls.levels[hls.currentLevel];
  console.log("width: "+level.width); // 0
  console.log("height: "+level.height); // 0
```

Is there a way to get the video size that is reported by the codec when playing?